# how to enter record in many to many relationship

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

- `Student`
- `Student_CourseInfo`
- `Course`

The table `Student_CourseInfo` contains `Student_ID` from `Student` Relation and `Course_ID` from `Course` Relation.

I want to insert a new record in `Student` and `Course` PLUS a record must also be inserted in the table `Student_CourseInfo`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you supply us with what you have tried so far, an example of your SQL and we can try point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to create all of these records in on go you would:

- lock all three tables
- create the student
- create the course
- create student_courseinfo

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: So what is the next step here...vote for the deletion of my own answer?

Answer (score 0):

just do an inser statement into the Student table, do an insert into the Course table, and then do an insert staement into the Student_CourseInfo table.  If this task will be completed multiple times, use a function (at least thats what i would do)